# How to make dao.merge in the same method for same datasets

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have @Transactional method, which can make merge for values presented in db or create the new one row if not.

In case it creates the new row, it doesn't fill one column.
That's why I need to rewrite them again to fill my column up with values.

So, for this I need that AFTER first call of the method will work the second one call, for the list of values I want to merge.

But it works like in the same time, which is a problem.

```
userService.saveAll(usersToSave);
userService.saveAll(usersToUpdate);
```

saveAll is a just @Transactional method.

I try to do smth like this, but it doesn't work. It tries to do it in the same time which is impossible in that case.

Note: the second list contains elements from the first one.

So the first list has all elements(for adding and merging), when the second one contains only added elements which has to be merged in saveAll.

Can i somehow divide my transactions in two different and run one after another?